# getClassloader failure reasons?

Tags: java, classloader

Just curious that when will the below line fail?

> this.getClass().getClassLoader();

ClassLoader will ALWAYS be found right ? is there any situation that the ClassLoader cannot be found ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader() - will fail due to permission issues or if this object represents a primitive type or void

Comment: Down-voted question for lack of research, since javadoc of [`getClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--) documents *"when will the below line fail?"*

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source code. This method throws only SecurityException when there is a SecurityManager and you are not permitted to access it.

```
public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
        ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();
        if (cl == null)
            return null;
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm != null) {
            ClassLoader.checkClassLoaderPermission(cl, Reflection.getCallerClass());
        }
        return cl;
    }
```

And in case you are wondering what `cl` could be `null`. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921238/getclass-getclassloader-is-null-why?rq=1).

Comment: No need to look at the source code. Both the `null` value and the security check is well documented in the javadoc of [`getClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--). The documentation is actually better, since it shows exactly what exception is thrown, which the shown source doesn't. It also explains what the `null` value *means*, which again the shown source doesn't. Always use javadoc as your first source of information about Java API methods.